# Run PHP code in a variable

Tags: php, variables

I want running PHP code in a variable.

I will use in MySQL.

```
$read = mysql_query("select * from table");
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
echo "$list[code]";}
```

*code in table:* **echo "asd";**

Output: `echo "asd";`

I want: `asd`

Or

```
$read = mysql_query("select * from table");
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
$list[code];}
```

It doesn't work. How can I do?

Comment: Terrible idea. [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) will help you accomplish your terrible idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working.

Comment: Muhammet, try to reconsider your design. It really is *incredibly* dangerous to use `eval()` in your code, **specially** if the code-to-be-ran comes from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval()` function for this case
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp